# MongoDB not installable from 10gen's Debian repository

Tags: debian

I added the official 10gen Debian repo to my Wheezy installation but MongoDB remains uninstallable:

```
Setting up mongodb-10gen (2.4.4) ...
[FAIL] Starting database: mongodb failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript mongodb, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mongodb-10gen (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up mmv (1.01b-15) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-10gen
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up mongodb-10gen (2.4.4) ...
[FAIL] Starting database: mongodb failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript mongodb, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mongodb-10gen (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-10gen
```

Did anyone install MongoDB successfully as .deb?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I followed the instructions here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/

After downgrading with

```
 apt-get install mongodb-10gen=2.2.3
```

It started

```
[ ok ] Starting database: mongodb.
```

If you want to make this change permanent to subsequent updates, mark this package to hold state use:

```
apt-mark hold mongodb-10gen
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a VM and started it with a relatively small size, it could just be due to a lack of free space. At this stage, MongoDB create the journal files and you need at least 3379MB available for that.

Otherwise check the log which should be at :

```
/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```